# RSpec send_file testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, sendfile

How to test a controller action that sends a file?

If I do it with `controller.should_receive(:send_file)` test fails with "Missing template" because nothing gets rendered.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

From [Googling](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/179408) [around](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/181545), it appears that `render` will also be called at some point .. but with no template, will cause an error.

The solution seems to be to stub it out as well:

```
controller.stub!(:render)
```

Comment: Nice, why didn't I think of that :)

Comment: For anyone viewing this using newer versions of RSpec, `stub!` has been deprecated. Just use `stub`

Comment: And in Rspec 3, it's `allow(controller).to receive(:render)`

Answer (score 26):

Another way that works is:

```
controller.should_receive(:send_file).and_return{controller.render :nothing => true}
```

To me, this captures the fact that the intended side effect of `send_file` is to arrange that nothing else be rendered.  (Albeit, it admittedly seems a bit wonky to have the stub call a method on the original object.)

Comment: Rails 4, RSpec 3: `'and_return { value }' is deprecated. Use 'and_return(value)' or an implementation block without 'and_return' instead.`

Answer (score 11):

You can also do this:

```
result = get ....

result.body.should eq IO.binread(path_to_file)
```

Answer (score 1):

This has worked great for me in RSpec controller tests. I prefer to not stub it out, but instead call the original so it does return the file and you can even access the response headers, etc...

```rb
expect(controller).to receive(:send_file).with(some_filepath, type: "image/jpg").and_call_original
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing request specs (you [should](https://medium.com/just-tech/rspec-controller-or-request-specs-d93ef563ef11)), spying on `send_file` will not be possible.

Instead, satisfy yourself with inspecting the response:

```rb
expect(response).to have_http_status(:ok)
expect(response.body).to be_present

expect(response.headers["Content-Disposition"]).to eq(
  "attachment; filename=\"document.pdf\"; filename*=UTF-8''document.pdf",
)
```

If you want to assert that the contents match the source file, you can, but this is generally excessive, and for generated content the assertions should be made on a service layer.

```
expect(response.body).to eq(record.file.download)
```